# Reading Esri file geodatabase (*.gdb) using DotSpatial?

Tags: file-geodatabase, .net, dotspatial

I am a big user of DotSpatial and have even contributed some source code. However, I am having some roadblocks in trying to figure out if DotSpatial can read a file geodatabase. I have posted on the official forum but don't think its very active right now.

Has anyone been able to do this with DotSpatial?

Comment: SharpMap has a C# data provider for the File geodatabase format.

Comment: Let me take a look. I think i already exhausted that avenue.

Answer (score 1):

If no one has already done this for DotSpatial, then a good starting point for you will be the [File Geodatabase API](https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api/tree/master/FileGDB_API_1.5.1):

> The API provides basic tools that allow the creation of file
>   geodatbases, feature classes and tables. Simple features can be
>   created and loaded. See the README included in each of the zip/tar
>   files for a more complete list. .NET bindings are included.

Comment: I will look into it. The hard part is integrating it into the DS framework.